# Lightning system datepicker icon not in input box?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Im building a lightning experience app and i have created a ui:inputDate field with *displayDatePicker="true"* But the date picker always appears outside the input box, or if i get it inside the input box, i lose the styling.

I am using salesforce lightning design system for styling.

**Code:**

```
<aura:component controller="risetest.lBookings"  implements="force:appHostable">

<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS090/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" 
              scripts="/resource/jquery,
                       /resource/moment" />

<aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="appointments" type="risetest__Appointment__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="newAppointment" type="risetest__Appointment__c"
                default="{ 'sobjectType': 'risetest__Appointment__c',
                                    'Name': 'Test',
                                    'risetest__Date__c': '',
                                    'risetest__Start_Time__c': '',
                                    'risetest__End_Time__c': ''}"/>

<div class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Appointment</div>
<div class="slds-m-top--small"></div>

<div class="container">
    <form class="slds-form--stacked">
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-is-required">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                     <ui:inputDate aura:id="AppointmentDate" label="Appointment Date"
                           class="slds-input"
                           format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                           labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                           value="{!v.newAppointment.risetest__Date__c}"
                           displayDatePicker="true" />              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <ui:button label="Submit" 
                   class="slds-button slds-button--neutral  slds-button--small"
                   press="{!c.createAppointment}"/>
        </div>



    </form>
</div><!-- ./container-->
<div class="slds-m-top--medium"></div>
```

**Here is what it looks like:**

[image]

**If remocve the class on the ui:inputDate :**

```
 <ui:inputDate aura:id="AppointmentDate" label="Appointment Date"
                           format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                           labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                           value="{!v.newAppointment.risetest__Date__c}"
                           displayDatePicker="true" />
```

**I get the following with no styling:**

[image]

Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

`<ui:inputDate>` generates a few elements when it gets rendered. The ones we're concerned with are an `<input>` element, and an `<a>` element that is used for your icon.

The CSS class `.slds-input` is applied to the `<input>` element and has the property `width: 100%` which is causing your `<a>` element to wrap because it comes after the `<input>` element in your DOM. There are a few ways to get around this:

1. Reduce the width of your date picker in the Style portion of your component
2. Add `white-space: nowrap` to the div that contains your `<ui:inputDate>` element.

I'm no CSS/HTML wizard, there may be some better solutions here, but your problem is definitely the `<a>` element wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

The current datepicker is a dog. I ran into the exact same issues with the icon placment.

Because of this, I have created a custom date picker which should solve any issues you may have. Also, if you run into issues, you will be able to fix them, since you will have defined the components. [Here](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2016/08/build-lightning-date-picker) is the blog post link.

This date picker is styled using the proper SLDS css, so will fit right into your SLDS Page or Lightning App.

I tried to eliminate any dependencies and would have fully succeeded except for a bug with the Locker Service (it seems to prevent some values being returned from string to date methods called on the `localizationService` object. Hence, it does require moment.js at present.

In your form, put the below(once you have created it) as a top level member of the form:

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-m-top--medium">
    <c:DatePicker aura:id="closeDate" label="Close Date" placeholder="Enter a Date" value="{!v.opportunity.CloseDate}" formatSpecifier="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</div>
```

In your component, you need to handle the `dateChangeEvent` from the component:

```
<aura:handler name="dateChangeEvent" event="c:DateChange" action="{!c.handleDateChange}" />
```

Finally, in your controller or helper update your date:

```
handleDateChange: function(cmp, event, helper) {
  var dateSelector = event.getSource().getLocalId();
  if (dateSelector == 'closeDate'){
    var opp = cmp.get("v.opportunity");
    opp.CloseDate = event.getParam("value");
  }
}
```

In the meantime, here is all the code on github: [Datepicker](https://github.com/rapsacnz/DatePicker)

Of course, a gif too:

[image: Datepicker gif]

Let me know if you find any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_dev/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_events) under *Bonus Lesson—Minor Visual Improvements* section you will find out the solution as below

**Salesforce Lightning Component for DatePicker Input**

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
          <ui:inputDate aura:id="expdate" label="Expense Date"
              class="slds-input"
              labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
              value="{!v.newExpense.Date__c}"
              displayDatePicker="true"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS for the above datepicker input**

```
.THIS .uiInputDate .datePicker-openIcon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 95%;
    top: 55%;
}
```

You will get the output as below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue and the way I fixed is by overriding the width, hope this helps you.

```
.THIS .slds-input{
    width: 50%
}
```

Comment: `width: auto;` will probably work better in most cases: don't have to give a specific width